# Does Magento merge all .xml file in the `etc` folder of a module?

Tags: magento2

I am wondering if It is possible for me to move XML content from **di.xml** to **config.xml**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain answer: No

Magento merge all di.xml separately from config.xml and di.xml and config.xml doesn't contain the same type of data.

Read: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html for more info on the di.xml

Read: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/config-files.html for more info on config.xml